# Clarification on Ternary Shortenings involving Null in Java

Tags: java, null, ternary

This site: [Information on the null constant in Java](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/null.html) states that the following two statements are synonymous:

```
if(PossibleNullVariable!=null)PossibleNullVariable.Action();
PossibleNullVariable!.Action();
```

Also, This site: [Information on avoiding null checks in Java](http://thetechcandy.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/avoid-null/) states that these two statements are synonymous:

```
String str = getStringMayBeNull()!=null?getStringMayBeNull():"";
String str = getStringMayBeNull() ?: “”;
```

Could I please get some clarification please? Thank you for your time. (:

Comment: did you type this in and try to compile? what happened?

Comment: You might be interested in [JSR 334](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr334/index.html) (Project Coin), which are the minor improvements to the language.

Comment: If you actually read the websites you linked, your question answers itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those are *suggestions* given by the authors of the articles as better ways of dealing with `null`.   Neither are currently in Java.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't notice that when reading. Makes sense that I couldn't find any other documentation of the subject.